# How to enable proxy service security in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 Policy file for Digest

Tags: web-services, authentication, digest, digest-authentication, wso2-esb

I have an issue using rampart in wso2 ESB to sign my soap messages, i use an XML policy attached to the outgoing endpoint, this policy need to specifies Password Digest as the algorithm to use for the digest (AlgorithmSuite : password Digest)

The problem is my wss security header is like below its set #PasswordText

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F8983EC106E3CD7A6915501268083805">
            <wsse:Username>userid</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">2DLoIevf9t75A7jm90+Anw==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2019-02-14T06:46:48.379Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>`enter code here`
```

what i need is wss security header like below its should set #PasswordDiges

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-F8983EC106E3CD7A6915501267560244">
            <wsse:Username>userid</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">SDSDSDDDSDDDDSDD==</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">SDSDRRERRsdDSDSDD==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2019-02-14T06:45:56.024Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
```

How can i do to make wso2 ESB sign a soap message using passowrd Digest  as the algorithm method for password digest ?

Comment: How does your policy file look like now?

Comment: @jan thanks i manage to configure that.
 <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Always">
                     <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:HashPassword/>
                        <sp:WssUsernameToken11/>
                     </wsp:Policy>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#PasswordDiges like below 

<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/…">
 <wsp:Policy> <sp:HashPassword/> <sp:WssUsernameToken11/> </wsp:Policy>
```